# CORS Issue when use Mailgun over HttpClient

Tags: angular, cors, sendmail, mailgun, angular-httpclient

I'm working with Angular 7 and trying to send email using Mailgun API, I got the below CORS Policy error even after enabling Headers Origin request from my side. Is that caused from the server side ? Or do I have to do some changes in the code below for it to work?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MailService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  sendEmail() {
    const header = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + 'api:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, x-requested-with',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
    });

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('from', 'zname <zname@sandboxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org>');
    formData.append('to', 'example@hotmail.com');
    formData.append('subject', 'Hello');
    formData.append('text', 'This is cool !');

    this.http
    .post('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org/messages',
    formData, { headers:header, withCredentials: true }).subscribe(
          res => { console.log('res : ', res); },
          err => { console.error('err : ', err); },
          () => console.log('data :', formData),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding the CORS headers here will unfortunately not have any positive on the issue. They instead need to be present on the response from the server.

Comment: You will maybe experience this issue on localhost only. For localhost you likely need to mock your response.

Answer (score 1):

Mailgun's documentation explicitly forbids you from doing this (and for good reason)

> NOTE: If used in the browser, a proxy is required to communicate with the Mailgun api due to cors limitations. Also, do not publish your private api key in frontend code.

https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun.js#mailgunjs-

Making calls like this for a service like email is akin to making database calls directly from a browser.  There's a host of security attack surfaces that are opened up.